# adding nodes to tree with unique pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am very new to smart pointers and I am trying to create a doubly tree where the child nodes are pointed from the parents by a unique pointer, and the children are pointing to the parents via raw pointer. So when A parent node gets destroyed the whole sub-tree will get destroyed in the process.

```
class Node {
private:
    Node *parent;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;
public:
    Node(Node* _left, Node* _right, Node* _parent);
};

Node::Node(Node* _left, Node* _right, Node* _parent) {
    parent = &_parent;

    //this is where the problem starts
}
```

I don't understand how to point to a new node that might have a tree I want to connect. If I use make_unique I believe that will create a new node Instead of preserving the tree.

I might be totally wrong about this since I just learned smart pointers about 4 days ago (Realistically enough time to learn something).

Comment: The things you are passing to the constructor are copies of nodes, which is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: Arguments passed by values are no different from other local variables, and will go out of scope once the function returns.

Comment: How can left and right be in the constructor? You are creating a node while already knowing the parent and the children?

Comment: well As I said in the explanation, I want the unique properties of the unique pointer class(where if it goes out of scope it gets deleted), but at the same time want access to its parents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, an empty tree is possible and a default constructed node will fit well.
Parent reference will be known at the time a node is attached so, child's node parent shall be updated once a node is set as left or right child of the current tree.

It might be a good idea to receive unique_ptr as you are taking ownership of the pointer you receive. Here is an example implementation:

```
class Node {
private:
  Node *parent = nullptr;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> m_left;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> m_right;

public:

  void left(std::unique_ptr<Node> child) {
    m_left = std::move(child);
    m_left->parent = this;
  }

  void right(std::unique_ptr<Node> child) {
    m_right = std::move(child);
    m_right->parent = this;
  }
};
```

You will use it like the following:

```
int main()
{
  auto tree = std::make_unique<Node>();
  auto subtree = std::make_unique<Node>();

  subtree->right(std::make_unique<Node>());
  tree->right(std::make_unique<Node>());
  tree->left(std::move(subtree));
  return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new to `unique_ptr` myself, hope someone will further correct me.
BTW don't use names hat that starts with `_` for your identifies, they are reserved.

Comment: "TW don't use names hat starts with _ for your identifies, they are reserved." Sometimes. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) I don't use them because I don't want an surprises if I accidentally violate one of the rules.

Comment: Well, that was my spirit too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use:

```
Node(Node _left, Node _right, Node _parent);
```

This won't allow to build the tree node by node. Instead, use:

```
Node(Node* _left, Node* _right, Node* _parent);
```

That way, you can create the first node using:

```
Node firstNode(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

From there, you can build other nodes.

To build a simple tree, with three nodes as below

```
            N1
           /  \
         N2    N3
```

you can use:

```
Node* N1 = new Node(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
Node* N2 = new Node(nullptr, nullptr, N1);
Node* N3 = new Node(nullptr, nullptr, N1);

N1->left = N2;  // Use the equivalent member function.
N1->right = N3;
```

Comment: Better to use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` or even `std::make_unique<Node>()` when constructing `N1`, `N2` and `N3`, and then `std::move()` `N2` and `N3` into `N1->left` and `N1->right`. Also, the `_left` and `_right` constructor parameters should be `std::unique_ptr<Node>` as well

Comment: Hey how did you build that tree? I might try and remember how and provide better questions this way.

Comment: @Dogunboundhounds, you mean the tree in ASCII art?

Comment: @RSahu Yes. How do I do that? In stackOverflow editor.

Comment: @Dogunboundhounds, just like writing code. Use the characters `/` and `\ ` to create the connections. It's a bit tedious if you are not used to it but not so bad after you get used to it.

Comment: @RSahu so you then put it in a "code block" to make it stand out. Wow now I feel real stupid.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, My compiler, g++ 5.4.0, does not support `std::make_unique`. Can't try the code before I post it. Don't want to post something that potentially has compiler errors.

Comment: @RSahu There are online compilers.

Comment: @Dogunboundhounds, no need to feel stupid. We call can learn from the tricks used by others around us.

Comment: @RSahu you can still declare `N1`, `N2` and `N3` as `std::unique_ptr` without having `std::make_unique()`, just use `new` directly, eg: `std::unique_ptr<Node> N1(new Node(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr)); ... `

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to make the parent, left and right child public. At least, this is how I have always implemented my nodes using a `struct` instead:

```
struct Node
{
    Node(std::unique_ptr<Node> _parent = nullptr, 
std::unique_ptr<Node> _left = nullptr, std::unique_ptr<Node> _right = nullptr) : parent(_parent), left(_left), right(_right) {}

    std::unique_ptr<Node> parent;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right;

};
```

Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: By necessity one `Node`'s `parent` is going to be another `Node`'s `left` or `right`. Not a very unique pointer if there are two pointers to it. OP has this part right.

Comment: @user4581301 ahh that makes sense. I have never really used `std::unique_ptr`, I have always used `std::shared_ptr` and wrongly assumed that unique and shared could be used in the same way.

Comment: Good answer describing what the various smart pointers are for in plain english: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143936/4581301 . The first answer to the question goes into better detail on how and when to use.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for the link. My professor showed me how to build a node using `std::shared_ptr`, so if we replaced all the unique with shared, would that be bad practice? Or is that acceptable if it gets the job done?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE&t=1864s Go to 22:41. This is why I posted this question

Comment: @Dogunboundhounds thanks for the link. Bookmarked. Sailanarmo, I make the `shared_ptr` call on a case-by-case basis. Sometimes it doesn't make sense for `Node`s to manage themselves because they don't know enough about the rest of the container to make the call (like cutting loose a node from a graph and not noticing the Node is part of a self-referencing cycle) a graph sitting lost in memory.. Sometimes the overhead of the `shared_ptr` hinders performance (there's more than just a simple reference counter variable in there).